# How to convert an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to List<List<String>> in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, n-queens

I'm working on the N-Queens problem on LeetCode, which stipulates that the return type for the main method is a `List<List<String>>`. I thought that if I made a global variable that was a `List<List<String>>`, then in main instantiated it as an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, I would be able to return as the proper type, but when I try to instantiate it gives the error: "Line 12: error: incompatible types: `ArrayList<ArrayList<StringBuilder>>` cannot be converted to `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`".

I was also under the impression that, because ArrayList implements List, you could return an instance of an ArrayList as a List, but when I make the global variable an ArrayList it gives the following error: "Line 15: error: incompatible types: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` cannot be converted to `List<List<String>>`". Printing out the boards that are considered valid I know I'm getting the right combinations, but this last detail has really frustrated me and I would very much appreciate any explanation for why I'm getting these errors. Thanks!

```
class Solution {
    ArrayList<Integer> colsUsed;
    ArrayList<Integer> leftDiagsUsed;
    ArrayList<Integer> rightDiagsUsed;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> solutions;

    public List<List<String>> solveNQueens(int n) {
        colsUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        leftDiagsUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        rightDiagsUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> board = createBoard(n);
        solutions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        return solutions;
    }

        public void iterateBoards(ArrayList<StringBuilder> board, int row, int n){
        if (row >= n){
            printBoard(board);
            addBoard(board);
            return;
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++){
            if (!colsUsed.contains(col) && !leftDiagsUsed.contains(row - col) && !rightDiagsUsed.contains(row + col)){
                colsUsed.add(col);
                leftDiagsUsed.add(row - col);
                rightDiagsUsed.add(row + col);

                board.get(row).setCharAt(col, 'Q');
                iterateBoards(board, row + 1, n);

                colsUsed.remove(new Integer(col));
                leftDiagsUsed.remove(new Integer(row - col));
                rightDiagsUsed.remove(new Integer(row + col));
                board.get(row).setCharAt(col, '.');
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<StringBuilder> createBoard(int n){
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> board = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>(n);
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++){
            row.append(".");
        }
        for (int currRow = 0; currRow < n; currRow++){
            board.add(new StringBuilder(row.toString()));
        }
        return board;
    }

    public void addBoard(ArrayList<StringBuilder> board){
        List<String> newBoard = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++){
            newBoard.add(board.get(i).toString());
        }
        solutions.add(newBoard);
    }

    public void printBoard(ArrayList<StringBuilder> board){
        for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++){
            StringBuilder curr = board.get(i);
            System.out.println(curr.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all variable *declarations* to use only the `List` interface. It's a good practice to use the widest possible type that you need in the declaration - for java.util collections, that's almost always the interface.

The fact that you chose to use an ArrayList (rather than, for example, a LinkedList) is an implementation detail that has no impact on the rest of your code.

```
class Solution {
    List<Integer> colsUsed;
    List<Integer> leftDiagsUsed;
    List<Integer> rightDiagsUsed;
    List<List<String>> solutions;

    public List<List<String>> solveNQueens(int n) {
        // [...]
        solutions = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Comment: Also solutions can be initialized with just: solutions = new ArrayList<>();